# Unable to submit form on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

i want to submit a form with and enter key stroke when the user enters a username and password.I get an alert coming back from my function when the enter key is pressed.But after that it doesnt submit the form. What am i doing wrong?

```
<form id="myForm" action="#" onsubmit="return false;" >
 <div>
 <input type="text" id="username"  />
 </div>
 <div>
 <input type="password" id="password"   />
 </div>
 <div>
  <button type="submit" id="btnLogin" onclick="myFunction(0)">Log in</button>
 </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction(e) {
        if ((e && e.keyCode == 13) || e == 0) {
            alert("The form was submitted"); // this alert gets called,but my form doesnt get submitted
            document.forms.myForm.submit();   
        }
    }
```

Comment: i think `myForm` should be the `name` instead of `id` for `document.forms.myForm` to work

Comment: `document.forms[0].submit()` if this is the only form on the webpage. Otherwise it has to be like @Kaddath comment

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings,its not the only form on my page,i have multiple

Comment: Please check your browser console for errors.  Do you have: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of undefined*?  If so, it's the `.forms.myForm' that's incorrect (confirming comments above).

Comment: Maybe its because you dont actually close your form tags?

Comment: @freedomn-m that is the error i am getting,what should i do?

Comment: @Kaddath it says name is not part of the form attribute

Comment: The fix is very simple: change `<form id="myForm"` to `<form name="myForm"` and leave everything else as it is (assuming no other issues).  (this is what @Kaddath 's comment is alluding to)

Comment: Alternatively, change `document.forms.myForm.submit()` to `$("#myform")[0].submit()` as it's tagged jquery.

Comment: @Jesse I don't know if this is what you meant, but `name` is perfectly valid for a form ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Form)). Just add `name="myForm"` for your selection to work, you can perfectly set the same name as the id (not beautiful, but valid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this.(Use jquery)

1.Change Input type submit to button

2.Change the code for submitting form

3.Write a keyPress event for the form

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <form id="myForm" action="test.html" >
     <div>
     <input type="text" id="username"  />
     </div>
     <div>
     <input type="password" id="password"   />
     </div>
     <div>
      <button type="button" id="btnLogin" onclick="myFunction(0)">Log in</button>
     </div>
    </form> 
    <script type="text/javascript">       
       function myFunction() {
       alert("form submitted");
       document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
       }
    $('#myForm').on('keydown', function (e) {
      if (e.which === 13) {
          myFunction();
         }
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you really need `javascript` for this as realistically pressing enter inside a form will usually submit the form.

> Notice in the example below that all we are really doing is targeting
>   the submit event for the form and this also includes hitting the enter
>   key.

**However to satisfy your question**

Using `jQuery` you could try binding the keypress event to the button click submit event.

Something like this:

```
$("#btnLogin").blur();
$('#btnLogin').focus().click();
```

p.s. remember to close your `<form>` tag with `</form>`

---

### Example

```js
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    var confirmSubmit = confirm("Submit the form?");
    if(confirmSubmit)
    {
      $("#btnLogin").blur();
      $('#btnLogin').focus().click();
    }
    else
      return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" action="yourPage.html">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="username" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="password" id="password" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" id="btnLogin">Log in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Remove `return false` from the form `onsubmit` event.

2) Remove `onclick` event from the button.

3) Using JS, bind a `submit` event to the form and do what you need in the event handler, as below:

```js
var loginForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
loginForm && loginForm.addEventListener('submit', myFunction);

function myFunction(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("form is about to be submitted...");
  loginForm.submit();
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="username" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="password" id="password" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" id="btnLogin">Log in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Even better, remove all the JS and keep only the form as in my answer. It would submit the form on enter as that's the default behaviour when there is a button/input with type `submit`!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this without checking `keyCode`. You can enter key from any `input` fields or `button` inside the `form`.

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  var username = e.target.querySelector('#username');
  var password = e.target.querySelector('#password');
  if(username.value && password.value){
    alert("The form was submitted"); 
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="#" onsubmit="return myFunction(event)">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="username" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="password" id="password" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" id="btnLogin">Log in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```